# debugging with logcat

Tags: android, logcat

Once having gotten used to logcat (on MAC) it is quite OK.

However there are two issues I would like to know if there is a way to improve them.

a) how many lines are stored in logcat? is there a way to increase this? sometimes I would like to log several thousand lines, but lines get deleted by some kind of logic which I yet need to understand.

b) searching is logcat is OK typing the search text in the search line, however it's more of a filter than a search. If I now want to start looking at the subsequent line lets say from the first occurance of the found text, one can't, since the cursor or line gets lost as soon as the filter is removed.

The only way now to actually go to the line is to look at the time stamp and revisit the complete log content manually searching for the line that the filter has shown before - not forgetting to press the "pause" btn so that scrolling back does not get interrupted by some system messages

I hope I could explain this well enough to be understandable :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understood, you talking about logcat window in Eclipse.

1. You can increase count of lines in this window by modifing `Window->Preferences->Android->LogCat->Maximum number of logcat messages to buffer` value.
2. You can open Terminal window and redirect logcat in file:

   adb logcat > $HOME/logcat.xt

than you can view this file in another Terminal window, search this file with your favorite text editor, filter it with grep etc.

Comment: thanks, but what a shame that this is not integrated in Eclipse itself - while it is practically a basic feature of the most simple SDKs