# How to increase the number of lines limit in aLogCat/Logcat on a device?

Tags: android, logcat

I'm trying to log some debug stuff on an Android device using aLogCat. Apparently the number of lines the log can contain is limited, so after a test session I get a truncated logs (first messages are gone).

I don't know if this limitation is imposed by the system itself or by aLogCat, but I need to increase the limit.

I found related answers about logcat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212805/debugging-with-logcat), but they seem both about a device connected to a PC, while I need the increased log size in a field.

I know aLogCat provides an autosave option, but 15 minutes (which is the minimal available period) is too large for my use case, because the log buffer loops after several minutes of testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogCat itself is a 64KB ring buffer. That cannot be increased except perhaps by building your own firmware.

If you are getting less than 64KB of history, that might be a limit imposed by aLogCat.

Comment: Unfortunately, the logs are usually something about 10Kb. I'd be happy to have 64Kb. All I can do by far is to split test sessions into smaller ones, which is inconvenient a little bit.